# How to get the Description of object?

Tags: custom-object

I have created a custom object from the C# code into Salesforce and now I want to show the details like object name, label, description, etc... 
I got some solution regarding that "describeobject" but it doesn't have any property like description, created by and modified by. How can I can get those fields? I want to load all the fields which Salesforce shows in its UI.

Here is the code ::

```
            WalkThrough.Partner.DescribeSObjectResult[] dsrArray =
                  binding.describeSObjects(new string[] { "Employee__c" });

            // Since we described only one sObject, we should have only            
            // one element in the DescribeSObjectResult array.
            WalkThrough.Partner.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = dsrArray[0];

            // First, get some object properties                  
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nObject Name: " + dsr.name);
```

In dsr array I want to get all the fields but it is not populating. Is there any other way to get description of employee object?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the relevant code? Which fields/properties are you seeing?

Comment: Does dsr have anything in it (are any of the fields populated?)

Comment: dsr has the fields like name , label, (bool)custom,which we can set for the particular object in my case the dsr.name is "Employee__c", dsr.custom= true, dsr.label = Employee Label